# Maintaining production and development featuresets - ant + git

Tags: git, ant

I have a project which has two feature sets:

a. the `production` one

b. the `development` one, which contains some additional plumbing to perform different tests and experiments.

I find myself maintaining two git branches and merging from one to another and vice versa in order to keep them in sync.

I would like to have the plumbing code in a separate project and to "inject" it by demand.

I did research on featureflags and it's not something I think would suit me, as I don't want to commit the plumbing code to the production branch at all.

I am thinking of some string manipulation script that will search for tags and inject the code or otherwise remove it and save it in a separate scratch file.

I would like to know if there are existing approaches to this kind of problem.

Comment: You’re talking about a dependency. What code do you write? Can you use its dependency manager?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I use ant. I can introduce some abstraction in a separate module that will have two implementations - empty for prod and non-empty for test, and have two build targets respectively, but as I see it, that will involve me putting the plumbing calls and the empty implementation in the prod. I would like to avoid that.